# Starcounter 2.3.1 and starcounter in visual studio 3.0.0 are not compatible

Tags: visual-studio-2017, starcounter

I am a newbie with Starcounter and I am trying to create a project by that. But unfortunately I have faced to an error when I try to create a simple hello world project! (I must use 2.3.1 version)
[image]

I have installed release version 2.3.1.8367 which automatically installed Starcounter in visual studio extension 3.0.0 and I have VS 2017.

[image]

As error says it is a problem with starcounter extension versioning but I can not downgrade to an older version. (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12764)

Anyone know how should I fix this?

Comment: I managed to fix that by

- Uninstalled all that I had
- Remove manually Starcounter extension
- Restart
- Install again which the key was to not automatically install extension (I removed the check at the beginning of the installation)
- Open the startcounter folder and looked for vsis and run manually.
You need to create the project again. I could not use created ones.

Answer (score 3):

@shrnPrmshr

Sorry to see you face this!

When you created your project, what template did you use? We are currently supporting two versions of Starcounter, where some project settings differ between the two.

So if you are on Starcounter 2.3, it's important you use template "Starcounter 2.3 Application". You'll see that template only if you target .NET Framework 4.5.* or .NET Framework 4.6.0. If you target 4.6.1, you'll see "Starcounter 2.4 Application", and at this point, that template doesn't work with Starcounter 2.3 out-of the box.

Could that be it do you think?

Best regards,
Per, Starcounter

Comment: I was targeting .NET Framework 4.5.* and template was Starcounter Application.

Comment: Noticed you got around it. Sorry we couldn't provide a smoother path than that. What I find confusing is you even see a template called only "Starcounter application" in extension 3.0.*. Templates there should include version in the name. Possibly, it could be something we didn't fully cover for when going from one version to another. Hard to say exactly. Be assure though we are constantly trying to improve in this area.

Let us know if you experience something else and we'll try our best to help!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever this problem occurs, we solve it with the following change to the `projectName.csproj` file: `StarcounterVersionCompatibility` from `2.4` to `2.3`.